# Hierarchical Smart playlists vs Smart playlists

Tags: itunes

What does the "..." button in the iTunes "Edit Smart Playlist" dialog do? And how is specifying a condition using that any different than a condition specified otherwise (by clicking the "+" button).

The only link I could find on that is [iPod nano: Hierarchical Smart Playlists do not update on device](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4387) and that doesn't clarify anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "..." allows to nest criteria for smart playlists.

Say you would like a smart playlist that contains all tracks from Bob Dylan or the Beatles with a score of 3 stars or better.

Without hierarchical rules you only have the options of getting the tracks that match **all** or **any** of your rules.

With hiearchical rules you can have the condition **all** on one level and **any** on another level.

It seems that nested rules exist since [iTunes 9; see also a screenshot](http://gigaom.com/apple/itunes-9-smart-playlists-are-now-smarter/).

Here is my example:

---

Match **all** rules

- Rating is greater than 3 stars
- **any** of the following

  - Artist contains Bob Dylan
  - Artist contains Beatles

Comment: Thats just great! I wanted to get back some hard disk space and tried Merlin Mann's tricks (http://www.43folders.com/2006/11/10/smart-playlists-for-packrats) but wanted a greater flexibility in doing it. Hierarchical rules provided just that.